# Splitting a string without delimiter and save it in an array

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to split three letters such as `WER` into three independent letters.
as follows:

```
W = array[0]
E = array[1]
R = array[2]
```

I tried the command

`WER | cut -c1` but I could not save the new string `W` in a variable.

I tried

`set var1 = WER | cut -c1` and it didn't work.

Comment: Why? For what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`:

```
str=WER

a=( "${str:0:1}" "${str:1:1}" "${str:2:1}" )
```

or, as a loop over an arbitrarily long string:

```
str=WER

a=()
for (( i = 0; i < ${#str}; ++i )); do
    a+=( "${str:i:1}" )
done
```

`${parameter:offset:length}` is a `bash` *substring expansion* that will result in the `length` number of characters of the string `$parameter` from offset `offset`.

Comment: For your first approach it gives: Bad : modifier in $ (0) but also for 1,2 etc.

Comment: @user309317, you used the "bash" tag in your question, but it looks like you're actually using csh or tcsh. Please clarify your question with details of which shell you're using.

Comment: @user309317 Make sure that you are actually using the `bash` shell (the question was tagged with `bash`).

Answer (score 1):

It's easier with `zsh`:

```
string=WER
array=(${(s::)string})
printf '<%s>\n' $array
```

(note that array indicies in `zsh` start at 1 like in most other shells, not 0 like in `bash`/`ksh`).

Or with `fish` (arrays also start at 1):

```
set string WER
set array (string split '' $string)
printf '<%s>\n' $array
```

(assumes `$string` doesn't contain newline characters though).

POSIXly (the POSIX shell has one array: `$@` (also starts at 1: `$1`)), so would also work in `bash` or `zsh` and your system's standard `sh`:

```
string=WER
set --
while [ -n "$string" ]; do
  tmp=${string#?}
  set -- "$@" "${string%%"$tmp"}"
  string=$tmp
done
printf '<%s>\n' "$@"
```

With `csh` or `tcsh` which you seem to be using:

```
set string = WER
set array = "`printf '%s\n' $string:q | fold -w1`"
printf '<%s>\n' $array:q
```

Like for `fish`, it also assumes the string doesn't contain newline characters. Also note that some `fold` implementations will fold on bytes instead of characters which would mean it wouldn't work properly  if the string contained multi-byte characters.

Comment: When I try your first approach I always receive: Illegal variable name.
Second one: Variable name must begin with a letter.
Third one: set -- does not work.

Sorry, but I am not really experienced with bash

Comment: @user309317, I think you missed the _with zsh_ and _with fish_ which are different shells from `bash`. The last one should work with `bash` as indicated.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, but I still get the error: 
set: Variable name must begin with a letter when I try the POSIXIy

Comment: @user309317, you tried the POSIXly in csh or tcsh, not bash nor any other POSIX shell.

Comment: Now it works. Is there also a possibility in csh?